# Does using "Nitpicking" have a bad influence on my WorkeMon?

Tags: workemon

In your company, you are able to use the option "[Nitpicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Da3.png)" to double the amount of money/experience generated by the WorkeMon for 3 seconds.

Is there anything bad that can happen if I keep using this option on my WorkeMon? Could their Loyalty stat go down if I use it a bit too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that I found multiple guides that mention that the way to maximize profits is to be nitpicking 100% of the time, it does not seem like there is any downside.

<sub>*(NOTE: does not apply to real life work environments)*</sub>

[This guide](https://www.touchtapplay.com/workemon-cheats-tips-strategy-guide-to-take-your-company-to-the-next-level/) was the first such one that I came across:

> Nitpicking: This is extremely useful as it increases the amount they produce, whether it’s XP or Money. You should Nitpick as often as possible especially early on since that will be your main way of making enough money to pay your Workemons and make a profit.

I also found [this guide](http://www.levelwinner.com/workemon-tips-cheats-strategy-guide-hints/):

> The process of Nitpicking is an especially important one in the early stages of the game, as that’s going to increase the coins or XP (depending on type) they produce. Make sure you’re doing this as often as possible, particularly in the early stages of the game. This is the best way to ensure you’re making enough money to afford your workers’ salaries, while still earning a tidy profit.

Thus, it seems like there's no reason not to constantly nitpick!